# Spotify OAuth without login form angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, spotify

I'm Building a simple web app for a recording studio. It fetches tracks from one, specific Spotify playlist using the angular-spotify library. https://github.com/eddiemoore/angular-spotify

I then grab that data and plug it into a little cover-art-grid audio player.

Everything is running smoothly -- until the OAuth token expires :/

How can I implement an authorization flow to allow my app to snag a refresh token without a login form in the angular library? I only need my own app to access my own playlist. (Spotify touches on this briefly in their documentation, but not in any great detail)

Here's the code I'm using right now to make the request that expires after a while.

```js
// private information in the config function has been swapped out for placeholders between "<>". 


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['spotify']);

//
app.config(function (SpotifyProvider) {
  SpotifyProvider.setClientId('<CLIENT ID>');
  SpotifyProvider.setRedirectUri('<REDIRECT-URI> ');
  SpotifyProvider.setScope('playlist-read-private');
//   // If you already have an auth token
  SpotifyProvider.setAuthToken('<OAUTH TOKEN>');
});

app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', 'Spotify', function($scope, Spotify){

  Spotify.getPlaylistTracks('oneofonedesignco', '5994q1H87nbxa1r2xSOW0s').then(function (data) {
    $scope.tracks = data.items;
    console.log($scope.tracks);
  });
```

Comment: I don't know the spotify API, thus only as comment: usually oAuth2 provides the ability to grant a `refresh_token` along with an `access token`. You may catch the expiration error and try to retrieve a new access token with the refresh token, then re-send the request (and store the new access token!)

Comment: That's exactly what I'd love to make happen! Can anyone help out with what that syntax would look like?

Comment: Hey @jamespwolpert, could you work this out?

Comment: Yes! I used node.js with the express.js server framework (hosted on heroku) to send out for a new token code whenever the route for the specific web-page is requested. I then pass the auth token to my angular app (with a get request) and pass the json data into a $scope -- done!